# How do I use QFtp::put to upload a file in Qt C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I would like to use QFtp to upload a text file to a FTP server.

This is the code I have :

```
QFile *file = new QFile("test.txt");
QFtp *ftp = new QFtp();

if(file->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
    ftp->setTransferMode(QFtp::Active);
    ftp->connectToHost(server);
    ftp->login(name, password);
    ftp->put(file, "test.txt");
    ftp->close();
}
```

After this code executes, I don't see anything on my ftp server. When I look at the documentation for QFtp::put, I see that the first parameter should be a QIODevice or QByteArray. How should I do this?

Edit:
So I have this code now:

```
//ftp.cpp
QFile *file = new QFile("test.txt");
QFtp *ftp = new QFtp();

this->connect(ftp, SIGNAL(commandStarted(int)), SLOT(ftpCommandStarted(int)));
this->connect(ftp, SIGNAL(commandFinished(int, bool)), SLOT(ftpCommandFinished(int, bool)));  
this->connect(ftp, SIGNAL(done(bool)), SLOT(ftpDone(bool)));
this->connect(ftp, SIGNAL(dataTransferProgress(qint64, qint64)), SLOT(ftpDataTransferProgress(qint64, qint64)));
this->connect(ftp, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), SLOT(ftpStateChanged(int)));

if(file->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
    ftp->setTransferMode(QFtp::Active);
    ftp->connectToHost(server);
    ftp->login(name, password);
    ftp->put(file, "test.txt");
    ftp->close();
}
```

with these functions:

```
//ftp.h
void ftpCommandStarted(int id);
void ftpCommandFinished(int id, bool error);
void ftpDone(bool);
void ftpDataTransferProgress(qint64, qint64);
void ftpStateChanged(int);

//ftp.cpp
void EmailDialog::ftpCommandStarted(int id) {
    this->messageBox("Command Started: " + QString::number(id));
}

void EmailDialog::ftpCommandFinished(int id, bool error) {
    this->messageBox("Command Finished: " + QString::number(id) + " Error: " + (error ? "Error" : "No Error"));
}

void EmailDialog::ftpDone(bool error) {
    this->messageBox("Done " + QString(error ? "Error" : "No Error"));
}

void EmailDialog::ftpDataTransferProgress(qint64 done, qint64 total) {
    this->messageBox("Done: " + QString::number(done) + " Total: " + QString::number(total));
}

void EmailDialog::ftpStateChanged(int state) {
    QString text;
    switch (state) {
        case 0:
            text = "QFtp::Unconnected";
            break;
        case 1:
            text = "QFtp::HostLookup";
            break;
        case 2:
            text = "QFtp::Connecting";
            break;
        case 3:
            text = "QFtp::Connected";
            break;
        case 4:
            text = "QFtp::LoggingIn";
            break;
        case 5:
            text = "QFtp::Closing";
            break;
        default:
            text = "";
            break;
    }
    this->messageBox(text);
}
```

However, I don't get any indication that the slots are being called. I don't have any message boxes popping up. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Much better now, but there is too much of the code missing for me to say what's wrong. could you upload it all to github or bitbucket?

Comment: It's been a while, you may consider picking an answer...

Comment: @RickSmith None of these worked. I eventually gave up on this and did something else.

Answer (score 2):

The code snippet you have looks correct (haven't tried compiling it though) so the problem probably lies somewhere outside of that snippet.

In response to the other answer, you do *not* need to catch signals to make the code execute.  Calling put, close, etc, will queue those commands and they will run when they are ready *regardless* of whether or not you are connecting to signals.  See "Detailed Description" in the [docs](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qftp.html).  That being said, I highly recommend connecting to signals because that is they way you get feedback for your users and for your debugging.

As far as why your current code is not working, the most common questions I would ask are:

1. Does the class containing the QFtp object extend QObject?
2. Does your header file contain the Q_OBJECT macro?
3. Have you rerun qmake since extending QObject or adding the Q_OBJECT macro?
4. Are you getting any "signal/slot does not exist" errors on your console? This usually means you have a typo in the name of your signal/slot.
5. Does your application have an event loop? [QFtp requires](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qftp.html) this because it queues its calls to happen asynchronously.  Also, all signals and slots need the event loop in order to work.  You start the event loop by calling exec on your QApplication which is usually in your main().
6. Do you have firewall rules blocking your ftp transfer?  You may need to use QFtp::Passive.

Those are the basic problems I can think of.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The QFtp class works asynchronously to transfer data. So, calling the connecToHost, put, error, currentCommand, and close functions sequentially will never actually execute any of the commands. What you need to do is write a class so that you can use signals and slots. Catching the signals after you start transferring is the key. The example listed in the QFtp detailed description gives some clarification to your issue/